# Как различать данные переданные через json?

Tags: php, json

Запрашиваю данные файлов с файл-сервера посредством основного сервера.

Файл-сервер возвращает данные в формате `JSON`.
Если возникли ошибки, пишет их в массив `$errors` и так же возвращает в формате `JSON`.

```
if (! file_exists($filePath))
{
    $file['hash'] = $fileHash;
    $file['size'] = filesize($fileQQQPath);

    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode($file);
}
else
    $errors[] = 'Такой файл уже существует в базе<br>';

if (isset ($errors))
{
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        echo json_encode($errors);
}
```

Проблема в том, что `JSON` удобен, но как мне различить где ответ, а где ошибки посланные в формате `JSON`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cоздайте постоянную пару: `type: message и type: error` (*расширяемо от полёта фантазии или ТЗ*), и проверяйте содержимое, тогда и другие пары **"значение - ключ"** могут отличаться:

```
{
       "type": "message",
       "content": "content"
    }
```